# pdfTex error for attachfile2 and vldb.cls

Tags: packages

For the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{vldb}%provided by https://vldb.org/2019/?formatting-guidelines

\usepackage{attachfile2}
\usepackage{xcolor}%not required, makes "click to open" readable
\usepackage{filecontents}%not required, for convenience

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{file.txt}
content
\end{filecontents}   
\textattachfile[color=blue]{file.txt}{click to open}
\end{document}
```

That produces the following error:

`pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfxform cannot be used with a void box. ...hfile[color=blue]{file.txt}{click to open}`

After some investigation, it seems that a single line in vldb.cls is responsible for this error as illustrated by the modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile2}
\usepackage{xcolor}%not required, makes "click to open" readable
\usepackage{filecontents}%not required, for convenience

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{file.txt}
content
\end{filecontents}
\newbox\savebox% from vldb.cls - comment to prevent error

\textattachfile[color=blue]{file.txt}{click to open}
\end{document}
```

Error:

`pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfxform cannot be used with a void box. ...hfile[color=blue]{file.txt}{click to open}`

What possibilities do I have to fix this issue? I may request a change for the cls if required. However, I would prefer an option that does not require to change the cls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if the class would have used the latex command `\newsavebox` it would have gotten an error and so avoided to redefine `\savebox`.

You could try

```
\let\orisavebox\savebox
\documentclass{vldb}
\let\savebox\orisavebox
```